# gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources via Vagrant, Puppet leads to @a(ss) []

Tags: keyboard, vagrant, puppet, gnome, gsettings

I try to configure GNOME keyboard layout via Vagrant, Puppet as follows:

```
gnome::gsettings { "input-sources":
   schema => "org.gnome.desktop.input-sources",
   key => "sources",
   value => "\"[('xkb', 'de')]\"",
}
```

As a result of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`, I get `@a(ss) []`. Where does this come from / what does these characters mean?

When I ssh into the box and set sources via the commandline, everything works.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question. There is no need to escape the double quotes. The following code works as expected:

```
gnome::gsettings { "input-sources":
   schema => "org.gnome.desktop.input-sources",
   key => "sources",
   value => "[('xkb', 'de')]",
}
```